# Show ion-nav-buttons position based on a scope variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an application that work in LTR or RTL mode, and im trying to update the menu to reflect the direction, so this is what i did:

```
<ion-view  id="home"  hide-back-button="true">

    <ion-nav-title>
        <img ng-src="{{logo_path}}" class="header-logo"/>
    </ion-nav-title>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="{{ (is_rtl) ? 'right' : 'left' }}">
        <button menu-toggle="{{ (is_rtl) ? 'right' : 'left' }}" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content class="has-header">
       ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the `is_rtl` is the variable set in the controller to know the direction. The problem is this does not have any effect. It appears that ionic does not parse the variable in the side part. Entering right or left manually works fine, but doesnt look it can work dynamically like. I even tried ng-if with no luck:

```
<ion-view  id="home"  hide-back-button="true">

    <ion-nav-title>
        <img ng-src="{{logo_path}}" class="header-logo"/>
    </ion-nav-title>


    <ion-nav-buttons side="left" ng-if="!is_rtl">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right" ng-if="is_rtl">
        <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content class="has-header">
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

### Update 1

I noticed The second try using `ng-if` partially works, but only if i navigated to a screen and returned back to the home screen, it does not work on initial load.

Comment: What's the current value of `is_rtl`? Would be better if you provide a simple **demo**.

Comment: just a true or false, i made sure it's set from the controller and returning the right value. ill try

Comment: You can use `ng-class` for this purpose where different classes with different position property will apply.

Comment: @HardikVaghani but its not the class attribute im targeting, its the side and menu-toggle

Comment: Please add a fiddle or a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick note, the `ion-nav-buttons` directive **must** be the first descendant of the `ion-view` for it to work. From the docs:

> Note that ion-nav-buttons must be immediate descendants of the
>   ion-view or ion-nav-bar element (basically, don’t wrap it in another
>   div).

It looks from the source code the `side` attribute is not being interpolated so no matter what you do, it'll always resolve to the html you pass. This is the [snippet](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/v1.3.1/js/angular/directive/navButtons.js#L57) from their compile function

```
var side = 'left';

if (/^primary|secondary|right$/i.test(tAttrs.side || '')) {
    side = tAttrs.side.toLowerCase();
}
```

Meaning that `tAttrs.side` will equal to `"{{is_rtl}}"` and not the actual boolean value.

Also it looks like ng-[if|show] will not work here because the lifecycle of the directive is being handled by the [$ionNavBarController](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/v1.3.1/js/angular/controller/navBarController.js#L64) on init.

In short it looks like your feature with ion-nav-button isn't possible at the moment. However you might be able to pull it off by setting the nav-bar hidden with `<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">` and then set your controls in a custom `ion-header-bar` like this:

```
<ion-header-bar>
    <div class="buttons" ng-class="{'buttons-right': is_rtl}">
        <span ng-class="{'right-buttons': is_rtl}">
            <button class="button button-clear">
                Right button block
            </button>
        </span>
     </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: i ended up changing the direction using css, very messy but works